# Querying with Dax in PowerBI : Syntax for ')' is incorrect

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to obtain some stats like the mean, median, standard deviation, and quantile of two columns through a single DAX query in a tabular format.

But getting this error-

```
The syntax for ')' is incorrect.
(DAX(VAR AVG = AVERAGE (
DATA[column1] VAR MED = MEDIAN (
DATA[column1] VAR SD = STDEV.S (
DATA[column1]...
```

and this just goes on.

I'm trying this

```
Stats_Cal_Col1 =

 VAR avg = AVERAGE ( DATA[column1] )


 VAR med = MEDIAN ( DATA[column1] )

 VAR SD = STDEV.S ( DATA[column1] )

 VAR Q20 = PERCENTILE.EXC ( DATA[column1], 0.50)

Stats_Cal_Col2 =
  
 VAR avg = AVERAGE ( DATA[column2] )

 VAR med = MEDIAN ( DATA[column2] )

 VAR SD = STDEV.S ( DATA[column2] )

 VAR Q20 = PERCENTILE.EXC ( DATA[column2], 0.50)
```

I'm trying to get input in a table like this-

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Average | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Median | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| SD | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Q20 | Cell 7 | Cell 8. |

Comment: Why not create separate measures, one for each one? Then I guess you can create a measure group.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stats_Cal_Col1 = 
VAR aveg = AVERAGE ( DATA[column1] )
VAR med = MEDIAN ( DATA[column1] )
VAR SD = STDEV.S ( DATA[column1] )
VAR Q20 = PERCENTILE.EXC ( DATA[column1], 0.50)
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [Column 1]="Average",aveg,
    [Column 1]="Median",med,
    [Column 1]="SD",SD,
    [Column 1]="Q20",Q20)
```

,

```
    Stats_Cal_Col2 = 
VAR aveg = AVERAGE ( DATA[column2] )
VAR med = MEDIAN ( DATA[column2] )
VAR SD = STDEV.S ( DATA[column2] )
VAR Q20 = PERCENTILE.EXC ( DATA[column2], 0.50)
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [Column 1]="Average",aveg,
    [Column 1]="Median",med,
    [Column 1]="SD",SD,
    [Column 1]="Q20",Q20)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this error- The value for 'column 1' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column.

Comment: Do you have the table you want with column 1 you show in last? Then create one table with Column 1 and these 4 items, then calculate these two columns.

Comment: Yeah, I do have a table with Column 1. Can you please show me what you have in Column 1?